# Smiliar to UIHint of ASP.NET MVC anything in Angular?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, angular, typescript

I am trying to create forms dynamically based on attributes.

So Let's say I have a model like below.

```
class Employee{
   id:number;
   name:string;
   address:string;
   pincode:String;     
}
```

What I want is, based on datatype or name of attributes, I want to create forms. So, for name I would create `textbox`, `textarea` for `address`, `textbox` with validation for `pincode`.

In `ASP.net MVC`, We have `UIHint` attribute to achieve similar thing. I am wondering if Angular has something like this.

Can someone suggest good approach to this?

Comment: If I understand correctly what you are asking, there is an example of building dynamic forms here: https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form (though it doesn't use attributes but rather through data structures.) With TypeScript, there are decorators, which are similar to C# attributes. You could build your own decorators, but AFAIK there is no build-in decorator for this.

Comment: @DeborahK, can we do something like this using decorators?

Answer (score 1):

Are you thinking something like this?

```
class Employee{
   id:number;
   @textbox() name:string;
   @textarea() address:string;
   @textbox() pincode:String;     
}
```

Yes, you could do something like that. but you would have to write all of the code to define/build/process the decorators.

Here is an article on how to build custom decorators: https://blog.angularindepth.com/implementing-custom-component-decorator-in-angular-4d037d5a3f0d

and this:

https://toddmotto.com/angular-decorators

Comment: I will try it out. Looks more complicated than I thought :D

Comment: Yes. It would be much easier to build dynamic forms following the technique identified in the documentation here: https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form

Comment: Thank you for your insight on this, I will go with a customized FormControl.